# How to create video element from base64 javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, video, base64, video-streaming

How do I create a video element from a Base64 data?

I am trying to load the entire video into memory, as the browser struggle to stream this 100MB mp4 file.
Since I want this video to play in a loop, I would like to just load it into memory and play it from there.
I did this with a blob, but it makes the app run very slow. I am not sure why, but I have seen others writing that create a video element from a blob, results in a very slow playback(without finding an answer).

So I am trying to create a video from a base64 string, but the video doesn't seem to be on a readystate.
Or doesn't call any callback saying the data was loaded.

The callback is never called and doesn't print "DataLoaded".

This is how I try to do this:

```
function CreateVideoElement(url, callback)
{
    var element = document.createElement('video');
    element.controls = false;
    element.style.display = "none";
    element.autoplay = false;
    element.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline');
    element.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
    element.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        callback();
    };
    element.src = url;
    return element;
}

function DownloadVideo(url)
{
    if (!videoFromMemory)
        return;
    fetch(url)
        .then(response = > {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        var u8 = new Uint8Array(response);
        var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
        var b64encoded = btoa(decoder.decode(u8));
        textureVideo = CreateVideoElement("data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encoded, function(){
            isDataLoaded = true;
            console.log("Data loaded");
        });
        console.log('Video Complete');
    })
        .catch (error = > {
        console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
    });
}
DownloadVideo("myUrl.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoded images are usually 20-30% larger than their corresponding JPG.  I would imagine a Base64 version of a 100MB video be much larger than the 100MB mp4 - potentially making your problem worse...

What are the dimensions of the video?  width/height/framerate?

Check with FFprobe (here is an API - just place your URL in the parameter:
https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=https://res.cloudinary.com/tamas-demo/video/upload/ac_none,c_scale,w_550/v1547201869/web-perf/IMG_0460.mp4)

Comment: I am ok with the file increasing by 30%, but I want it to be in RAM, so even if it's bigger it will stream better from RAM than from the network.